# DECIMAL and NUMERIC datatype in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, rdbms

what is the use of `decimal` and `numeric` datatype in postgreSQL. As per the reference the following is the explanation given to these datatypes.

```
decimal,numeric --> It is a user specified precision, exact and range up to 131072 digits before the decimal point and up to 16383 digits after the decimal point.
```

The above statement shows the description of `decimal` and `numeric` datatype. But, still I didn't understand what is the
    exact use of these data type and where it is used instead of other datatypes.

Answer with example is much appreciated...

Comment: Cross post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33730538/330315

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the x-posted question on SO does the job. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33730538/difference-between-decimal-and-numeric-datatype-in-psql)

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html)

> The types `decimal` and `numeric` are equivalent. Both types are part of
>   the SQL standard.

`float`, `real`, ... and the rest of the floating point types are inexact. This happens in all programming languages. As you have a type like [BigDecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3730040/930271) in Java to represent exact numbers, in PostgreSQL you have `decimal` and `numeric`.

They are commonly used to represent currency.